# Scrollbars are not appearing on expanding FoldPanelBar in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

When the fold panels expand, it goes outside of the frame and scroll bars are not appearing. I tried using a ScrolledPanel, but did not help. Any idea what I am missing here?

```
import wx
from wx.lib import scrolledpanel
import wx.lib.agw.foldpanelbar as fpb
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as sp

class MyPanel(sp.ScrolledPanel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        sp.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=parent.GetSize(), style = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        #self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        ##self.boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)###
        csStyle = fpb.CaptionBarStyle()
        csStyle.SetFirstColour(wx.Colour(190, 190, 190, 255))
        csStyle.SetSecondColour(wx.Colour(167, 232, 146, 255))
        csStyle.SetCaptionFont(wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        m_pnl = fpb.FoldPanelBar(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                            fpb.FPB_VERTICAL)

        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 1", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)

        self.listContainer = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer)
        btnAutoFix = wx.Button(item, wx.ID_ANY, "Go", size=(50,-1))
        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, btnAutoFix)
        ###self.boxSizer.Add(m_pnl)##


        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 2", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)
        self.listContainer2 = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer2)

        self.pnl = m_pnl
        ##self.SetSizer(self.boxSizer)###

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, size=(650, 400), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
    panel = MyPanel(frame)
    # Add sizer information for the scrolled panel
    szmain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    szmain.Add(panel.pnl, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
    panel.SetSizer(szmain)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible using the `FoldPanelBar` class. If you catch the `EVT_CAPTIONBAR` event and `print self.pnl.GetSize()`, it is always a constant value, meaning that the `FoldPanelBar` never resizes. You could probably use `wxCollapsiblePane` instead, but you wouldn't be able to customize its appearance.

Comment: Duplicate, see [the parallel post in wxpython-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/tzjhIIttjH4)

Comment: But there is no resolution yet. Seems like it doesn't support scrollbars :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `FoldPanelBar`'s default size. For some reason, it seems to make the widget behave in a dumb manner. If you specify a size, the scrollbars appear correctly.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.foldpanelbar as fpb
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MyPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent=parent,
                                        size=parent.GetSize(),
                                        style = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        #self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        csStyle = fpb.CaptionBarStyle()
        csStyle.SetFirstColour(wx.Colour(190, 190, 190, 255))
        csStyle.SetSecondColour(wx.Colour(167, 232, 146, 255))
        csStyle.SetCaptionFont(wx.Font(9, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        m_pnl = fpb.FoldPanelBar(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, (600,800),
                            fpb.FPB_VERTICAL)

        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 1", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)

        self.listContainer = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer)
        btnAutoFix = wx.Button(item, wx.ID_ANY, "Go", size=(50,-1))
        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, btnAutoFix)
        self.boxSizer.Add(m_pnl)


        item = m_pnl.AddFoldPanel("Set 2", collapsed=True, cbstyle=csStyle)
        self.listContainer2 = wx.ListCtrl(item, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(0, 'Column1', width=250)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(1, 'Column2', width=150)
        self.listContainer2.InsertColumn(2, 'Column3')

        m_pnl.AddFoldPanelWindow(item, self.listContainer2)

        self.pnl = m_pnl
        self.SetSizer(self.boxSizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You might consider [submitting a bug](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) for this to the wxPython project.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. When I pass in a size, scroll bar appears even if there are very few items. But that serves the purpose. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help